# Celery Module Tasks are Cached so edits in dev environment do not apply

Tags: python, docker, celery, supervisord

I have a problem which makes local development with Celery very difficult.

If I edit my local files and restart docker containers none of the CODE changes are applied. Not talking about task result caching here... just the actual function execution.

I have to prune everything for them to be applied.
Does anyone have any solution for this?

supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true


[program:celeryworker]
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=celery -A worker.scheduler.schedule.celery_app worker -l info 

[program:celerybeat]
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=celery -A worker.scheduler.schedule.celery_app beat -l info
```

worker.Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install supervisord
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pymysql

# copy requirements and install (so that changes to files do not mean rebuild cannot be cached)
RUN mkdir worker 
COPY worker/requirements.txt /usr/src/app/worker
COPY worker/supervisord.conf /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r /usr/src/app/worker/requirements.txt

# copy all files into the container
COPY ./worker /usr/src/app/worker
COPY ./db /usr/src/app/db

# needs to be set else Celery gives an error (because docker runs commands inside container as root)
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT=1

# run supervisord
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

compose subset

```yaml
  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: server
      dockerfile: worker.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./worker:/tmp/worker
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672//
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://@redis:6000/0
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
```

Comment: are you mounting your local files into the docker container?

Comment: just updated to show more info... theres not much copy over... I even deleted __pycache__ on my host and restarted the container... thought that would do it.

Comment: "      - ./worker:/tmp/worker" I don't see how /tmp/worker is relevant here.  In the docker build you copied that to `/usr/src/worker` so why would celery be getting updated code in `/tmp/worker`?

Comment: Do your RabbitMQ broker and Redis store have published `ports:`?  If you, then you can use a plain Python non-Docker virtual environment for ordinary development, pointing those environment variables at `localhost` rather than the Docker-internal names.